# Bootloader missing after USB install

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, bootloader

I've tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 from USB following the official instructions I created the USB key and started the install.

I chose to install Ubuntu alongside Windows and kept the suggested partitioning scheme.

At the end of the install I rebooted and the bootloader is not there and Windows boots.

I have tried with both Universal USB Installer (suggested on the Ubuntu site) and with Unetbootin.

Comment: Please run boot info script http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/ and post the RESULTS.txt which it produces.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I've since lost patience and nuked all other partitions and I'm installing Ubuntu alone. Hopefully this time it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the boot loader was installed on my USB.

I fixed it by booting into Linux with the USB and then run `grub-install` on the drive (`/dev/sda` in my case) again, which will install and configure grub to the drive.

Answer (score -1):

Put windows disk and click on Repair.
Start command prompt

Type

```
Bootrec.exe/fixmbr
Bootrec.exe/fixboot
```

You should get your Bootloader back.

**Edit** In case you  don't have installation media:

- You can download recovery disk from your Manufacturer.
- You can    download , master boot record disk and use it to repair
  boot record.
- You can do complete system backup using your Backup Drive. (
  Provided    as recovery disk from manufacturer.)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any Windows media: it came preinstalled on my Lenovo laptop. What alternatives do I have?

Comment: He is saying that he can boot windows. Does your command bring back Ubuntu

Comment: If look at my answer, it repair boot record. It can bring Ubuntu Back